# Mocking Django's RequestContext class

Tags: python, django

I am trying to mock Django's RequestContext class to return a key piece of data for my tests:

Here is the implementation:

from django.template import RequestContext

```
def oauth(request, provider):                       
    response = HttpResponse()                       
    print(RequestContext(request))   --->>> Prints out a magic mock               
    site_name = RequestContext(request)['site_name']
```

Here is my test:

```
@patch('core.views.Authomatic')                                 
@patch('core.views.RequestContext')                             
def test_new_user_redirects_to_sign_up_page(  # noqa            
        self, MockAuthomatic, MockRequestContext):              

    MockRequestContext.return_value = {'site_name': 'jacaranda'}
    print(MockRequestContext()) --->>>> prints out the dict
```

My view prints out a MagicMock instance, so I am obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for

```
@patch('core.views.RequestContext')
@patch('core.views.Authomatic')
def test_new_user_redirects_to_sign_up_page(  # noqa            
    self, MockAuthomatic, MockRequestContext):
```

The order of patches should be reversed

Comment: Missed the ordering and was looking for something really weird. Sorry for misleading you. Check the updated answer